# How to get value from a collection base on key name condition?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, query-builder

I am trying to get the value from a collection in PHP.

`$todaylog` variable contains a collection from a laravel query builder:

```
   $todaylog = [
   {
      "row_id":55,
      "emp_number":"IPPH0004",
      "timestamp":"03:30:23",
      "attendance_status":"Punch In",
      "date_created":"2021-10-01"
   },
   {
      "row_id":56,
      "emp_number":"IPPH0004",
      "timestamp":"11:32:50",
      "attendance_status":"Start Break",
      "date_created":"2021-10-01"
   },
   {
      "row_id":57,
      "emp_number":"IPPH0004",
      "timestamp":"11:33:09",
      "attendance_status":"End Break",
      "date_created":"2021-10-01"
   }
   ]
```

What I have done so far: but this approach is so slow:

```
$timein = DB::table('attendance')->select('timestamp')->where('attendance_status','Punch In')->get();
```

Now I want to have something like this: (PS this is only a pseudo code)

```
$timein = (where) $todaylog.attendance_status = "Punch In"
$endbreak = (where) $todaylog.attendance_status = "End Break"
```

Is this possible? or I have to query them to the database individually? Thanks

Comment: Do you need the rest of the collection for something else or would constraining the query be ok? How many rows (roughly) do you have in your `attendance` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need in Laravel is something like that:

```
$rows = collect([
       [
           "row_id" => 55,
          "emp_number" => "IPPH0004",
          "timestamp" => "03:30:23",
          "attendance_status" => "Punch In",
          "date_created" => "2021-10-01"
       ],
       [
           "row_id" => 56,
          "emp_number" => "IPPH0004",
          "timestamp" => "11:32:50",
          "attendance_status" => "Start Break",
          "date_created" => "2021-10-01"
       ],
        [
           "row_id" => 57,
          "emp_number" => "IPPH0004",
          "timestamp" => "11:33:09",
          "attendance_status" => "End Break",
          "date_created" => "2021-10-01"
       ]]);

    dd($rows->where('row_id', 57));
```

Result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#446 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    2 => array:5 [▼
      "row_id" => 57
      "emp_number" => "IPPH0004"
      "timestamp" => "11:33:09"
      "attendance_status" => "End Break"
      "date_created" => "2021-10-01"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you also check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69413269/how-to-calculate-total-hoursminutes-attendance-breaktime-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

you can use laravel collection [where](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-where) method:

```
collect($todaylog)->where("attendance_status", "Punch In")->first();
```

Comment: can you also check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69413269/how-to-calculate-total-hoursminutes-attendance-breaktime-in-laravel