# How to calculate total hours:minutes attendance breaktime in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, query-builder

I have an `$attendace` variable contains a collection from a Laravel query builder:

```
$attendance = collect(DB::table('attendance_copy')->where('emp_number', Auth::user()->emp_number)->where('date_created', $datenow)->get());
```

This is the result:

```
[
   {
      "row_id":65,
      "emp_number":"IPPH0004",
      "time_stamp":"01:00:00",
      "attendance_status":"Punch In",
      "date_created":"2021-10-02"
   },
   {
      "row_id":68,
      "emp_number":"IPPH0004",
      "time_stamp":"07:30:00",
      "attendance_status":"Start Break",
      "date_created":"2021-10-02"
   },
   {
      "row_id":69,
      "emp_number":"IPPH0004",
      "time_stamp":"08:00:00",
      "attendance_status":"End Break",
      "date_created":"2021-10-02"
   },
   {
      "row_id":70,
      "emp_number":"IPPH0004",
      "time_stamp":"08:30:00",
      "attendance_status":"Start Break",
      "date_created":"2021-10-02"
   },
   {
      "row_id":71,
      "emp_number":"IPPH0004",
      "time_stamp":"09:00:00",
      "attendance_status":"End Break",
      "date_created":"2021-10-02"
   }
];
```

What I have done so far (This works when only 1 `start break` and `end break` is present):

```
$startbreak = strtotime(( isset( $attendance->where('attendance_status', 'Start Break')->first()->time_stamp  ) == null ? "00:00:00" : $attendance->where('attendance_status', 'Start Break')->first()->time_stamp));
$endbreak = strtotime(( isset( $attendance->where('attendance_status', 'End Break')->first()->time_stamp  ) == null ? "00:00:00" : $attendance->where('attendance_status', 'End Break')->first()->time_stamp));


$minsbreak = date('i',$endbreak - $startbreak);
```

But in my case, there will be many breaktime recorded per employee throughout the day. I want to calculate how many hours:minutes an employee takes break:

from the collection above (12hr format), it should be `01:00 total hrs`. since `7:30 to 8:00 is 30mins`, and  `8:30 to 9:00 is another 30mins`. there will be 5 max breaktime.

Is this possible? or should I redesign my attendance table? Thanks

Comment: You want to show all breaktimes even though the total breaktimes is more then 5 and more then 30 minutes?

Comment: @RuiCosta it is the time difference of the pair Start Break and End Break which makes 30mins each.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the collection has already been filtered by `employee_number` and that the state after `Start Break` must be `End Break`.

```
$total_break_time = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($attendance); ++$i) {
    if ($i == 0)
        continue;

    if ($attendance[$i-1]['attendance_status'] == 'Start Break') {
        $previous_timestamp = strtotime($attendance[$i-1]['date_created'] . ' ' . $attendance[$i-1]['time_stamp']);
        $current_timestamp = strtotime($attendance[$i]['date_created'] . ' ' . $attendance[$i]['time_stamp']);
        $total_break_time += ($current_timestamp - $previous_timestamp);
    }
}

echo gmdate('H:i:s', $total_break_time) . PHP_EOL;
```

`$total_break_time` is the number of seconds. the `gmdate` function converts this into hours, minutes, seconds, returning `01:00:00`.

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: The code you posted in your question for `$attendance` is not valid PHP. What code is used to create `$attendance`?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `collect()` function?

Comment: after removing collect() function I still got the same error

Comment: OK, I notice collections have a `toArray()` method: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-toarray